# how can I get the substring in Python

Tags: python, regex

String just like '半球/一球\n0.90\xa01.10', how can I get substring '半球/一球','0.90','1.10' using regex,Thank you.

Comment: So do you just want to remove the `\xa0`?

Answer (score 1):

Symbol `'\xa0'` is a non-breakable space. You can remove it using `split()`, the same way you would remove any other white space, and then join the fragments. No need for regex.

```
",".join(s.split())
#'半球/一球,0.90,1.10'
```

Comment: Perhaps I did not understand your question correctly. Do you want _three_ substrings? Then simply do not do `join`. You do not need any regexes here.

Comment: thanks for your reply,split can do it ,not need regexes.